# No comet message when overriding blueprint CRUD action in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, sails.js

Goal is:

- Get comet message to work with overridden methods in controller like UPDATE or CREATE or DESTROY.

When i don't do override in controller SailsJS for UPDATE, i get comet message when i say socket.on('message').
Code is this:

```
#listening socket for new apps
socket.on "message", (data) ->
  console.log data
  if data.model is "application"
    viewModel.apps.push(new App(data.data))
  if data.model is "configuration"
    #rewrite this
    return
```

But this is never fired when i override method in my case UPDATE.
No matter what res i return never fires it up, I'm using `res.json()`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the blueprint hook for update, you have to handle the pub/sub of models for your custom routes.
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/update.js

You need to call  Model.publishUpdate and Model.subscribe